# gdb print file name line number when program is running

Tags: c++, gdb

I need to debug a flow using gdb - I do not know the call stack hence cannot set break points and going thru first entry points will be really very tedious in project code that runs thru thousands of line.

In same regards is there a way that when I start the program execution via gdb we enable some commands (after some initial breakpoint) - hence when the program starts processing further on it print file name line number without user interaction - something like code flow itself?

Comment: You can change a variable when the program is at a breakpoint, is that what you're asking?

Comment: Well I want to list lines of code when executing via GDB - like we do when breakpoint is set and we run 'step'. Is there a way that GDB prints code automatically when program is running?

Comment: Yes, but I've never used it.  https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html  I think will help you

Comment: Well will it list lines of code it is executing - I am not sure if those settings will enable printing lines of code - something like bash 'set -x' command - it prints what it is executing and the script flow

Comment: It'll print whatever you tell it to print - if you add `bt` it'll print the backtrace every time it hits your break point for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well I want to list lines of code when executing via GDB - like we do
>   when breakpoint is set and we run 'step'.

You can run `step` in infinite loop like this:

```
(gdb) start 
Temporary breakpoint 2, main () at ttt123.cpp:23
23      vector<A> v1;
(gdb) while 1
 >step
 >end
```

Comment: Thanks - it helped but can I now store whatever GDB prints on console to a file - the GDB messages are printing fast and screen scrolls - is there any other way also in case there are thread or some other techniques - this is just seeing if some other mechanism is there?

Comment: Yes, do `set pagination off`, `set logging on` before infinite loop and output will be saved to `gdb.txt` file by default.